# Use dynamic named query (@NamedNativeQuery) in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm in a unique situation where I need to include a unique random number as a comment within a query in order to debug an issue.

I'm using @NamedNativeQuery as below:

Entity.java

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "myQuery",
        query = NativeQuery.MY_QUERY, // throws compilation error
        resultSetMapping = "someEntityMapping"
)
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity {
...
}
```

Here is `MY_QUERY`:

```
public final class NativeQuery {
private NativeQuery() {
    }

public static final String ACCOUNT_HISTORY_BY_PARTY_ID = "/*[ID: " + RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(8) + "]*/ SELECT col_1 FROM ABC";
}
```

The code does not compile stating that I need a constant value in the attribute.

Is there any other way to achieve that? I cannot include an additional column in the table as that's simply not allowed.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further why you need this? Is your intention to read from the logs whenever the query is executed? If that's the case, why not simply log a message right before you call the query? As for the reason: JPA requires constants in order to work. Any type of variable would throw an error (I've tried that myself for a different purpose). The closer you can get to this is by using the EntityManager directly.

Comment: I’m investigating a problem with Splunk potentially not capturing all the query logs. This query will be fired by 100users at once as part of a performance test suit. The logs that I get from database supposedly shows far more queries than Splunk. Couldn’t find an easier way to compare and find which query is missing (if any).

Comment: Well, I unfortunately (to me) cannot say I understand, but at least is clearer why you'd need this. I can provide a very simple example of direct EntityManager usage if you'd like, but I suspect it won't be of much use in the end